# spherical mapping artefacts

Tags: webgl, texturing

I have some problems with sphere map texturing in webgl.

My texture:

[image]

Now I texturize a sphere. Everything is OK, if the sphere is in front of the camera:
[image]

The sphere is a unit-sphere (r = 1), defined with longitudes and latitudes.

But i get some artefacts, if i translate the sphere in x-direction -2.5 (without rotating the camera):
[image]

This image is without mipmapping. And the following image is with mipmapping:

[image]

Vertices and normals seems to be ok.

vertex-shader:

```
precision highp float;

uniform mat4 mvMatrix;  // Matrix zum Transformieren des Verex vom model-space in den view-space
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix; // Matrix zum Transformieren des Vertex vom model-space in den clip-space
uniform mat3 mvNMatrix; // Matrix zum Transformieren der Vertex-Normale vom model-space in den view-space

attribute vec4 mV;  // Vertex im model-space
attribute vec3 mVN; // Vertex-Normale im model-space

varying vec2 vN;

void main(void)
{
   vec3 e = normalize( vec3( mvMatrix * mV ) );
   vec3 n = normalize( mvNMatrix * mVN );

   vec3 r = reflect( e, n );            
   //float d = dot(n, e);
   //vec3 r = e - 2.0 * d * n;

   float m = 2.0 * sqrt( 
      pow( r.x, 2.0 ) + 
      pow( r.y, 2.0 ) + 
      pow( r.z + 1.0, 2.0 ) 
   );
   vN.s = r.x / m + 0.5;
   vN.t = r.y / m + 0.5;

   gl_Position = mvpMatrix * mV;
}
```

And fragment shader:

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;
varying vec2 vN;

void main(void)
{
   vec3 base = texture2D( uSampler, vN ).rgb;
   gl_FragColor = vec4( base, 1.0 );
}
```

Does anybody know, why i get these artefacts? I am working with windows and firefox.

Comment: And what happens if you move the object just slightly to the side? Or if you animate side-to-side motion smoothly?

Comment: No problems at a x-translation with -1. But i get artefacts with -1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your surface normals are backward, or you're culling the wrong side in general. You've done something like [azimuthal projection](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Dither/ProjAz/projAz.html#Stereographic), but you're rendering the inside of the sphere instead of the outside, so you're seeing greater than 180 degrees, including the 'bridge' separating forward and back. See also: [map projections](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Dither/CartProp/DefPatA/defPatA.html), which shows that azimuthal mapping is conformal everywhere but excludes at least the true equator with line of sight.