# Differences between spherical mapping techniques

Tags: graphics, 3d, texturing, ps2

I am working on a game engine with no pixel shaders and on a fixed function GPU. I am trying to implement spherical mapping and coming across the problems with seams and artefacts when the texture wraps to the other side, similar to [spherical mapping artefacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374642/spherical-mapping-artefacts). This only happens when I use a normal matrix to convert the normals and not when I use an object's world transform to convert normals.

I am trying to implement a view-dependent spherical mapping scheme and have tried the two methods explained in these articles: https://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_texturing_p04.php and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/spherical-environment-mapping. The former gives worse results than the latter, and the latter works perfectly with world space transforms.

I am just looking for any information as to why this happens and what can be done to prevent. I am aware that changing the vertex data for the sphere might help, but if there is a programmatic way to do it that would be helpful. You can see implementation to change texture coordinates for in this file on github in function SphereMappingCPU: https://github.com/crypt4489/PS2-Development/blob/master/src/main.c There are other implementations in source code as well. First picture is microsoft article implementation, second is ozone3d.net implementation using reflect equation.

[image: Distortion caused by using microsoft article implementation:]

[image: Distortion caused by using ozone3d.net implementation:]